# Confusion over namespaces in doc comment tests

Tags: unit-testing, rust

Very new to Rust, and I've run into an issue with trying to get doc comment tests working.

I'm hoping to have a module that *isn't* public, but has some tests in the doc comments.

src/lib.rs:

```rust
pub mod module;

fn foo() {
    println!("{}", module::get_hello());
}
```

src/module.rs:

````rust
/// Gets a nice Hello message
///
/// ```
/// use test_namespace::module::get_hello;
/// let msg = get_hello();
/// assert_eq!(msg, "Hello, World!".to_string());
/// ```
pub fn get_hello() -> String {
    "Hello, World!".to_string()
}
````

The only way I've been able to get this test working is if I have `pub mod module;`. I feel like there should be some way of running this test without the `use test_namespace::module::get_hello;` at all since it's a test in the same module. Hoping to get some clarification.

Comment: From [the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/documentation-tests.html): *"Note that they will still link against only the public items of your crate; **if you need to test private items, you need to write a unit test.**"*

Comment: More details: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/doctest-of-private-functions/60805